# NativeScript Email validation is not working

Tags: validation, nativescript, form-control

I'm need to verify that entered text im my TextField is an email. I'm usually using Form Group to do this. In my Form Control property im using "updateOn: 'blur'. But I have problem if I have only 1 TextField in current view. It seems like (blur) is not called.

I'm do this in few other places in my app but only there it don't work. Only difference is that there is only one TextField in component, and in others is few more (2-5).

'''''HTML

```
<TextField id="field" class="input" hint="E-mail" keyboardType="email" returnKeyType="done" formControlName="email" #emailQ [ngClass]="{niepoprawne: !emailQValid}" (returnPress)="wyslij()"></TextField>
    <Button text="Wyślij" class="button" (tap)="wyslij()"></Button>
```

'''''''TS
export class ZapomnialemComponent implements OnInit {

```
form: FormGroup;

@ViewChild('emailQ', { static: false }) emailQRef: ElementRef<TextField>;

emailQValid: boolean = true;

wyslanePrzyp: boolean = false;

constructor() {

}

ngOnInit() {


    this.form = new FormGroup({
        email: new FormControl(null, { updateOn: 'blur', validators: [Validators.required, Validators.email] })
    });


    this.form.get('email').statusChanges.subscribe(status => {
        this.emailQValid = status === 'VALID';
    });
}

wyslij()
{
    if(!this.form.valid)
    {
        this.displayAlertDialog("Wprowadź poprawny adres e-mail")
        return;
    }

    this.wyslanePrzyp = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have only one text field in your form and have set `updateOn` to `blur`. Your text field will not hit blur unless you change the focus to next field Or programatically remove focus from the text field.

Comment: Ok, so which I will choose? I have three 'updateOn' options: blur, change and submit.

Comment: Just leave it to the default (`change`).

Comment: Ok, thakns it works. Could you tell me more how to use (submit) property ? I think it will be usefull with many areas to validify.

Comment: I don't think submit will work, we don't have a concept of actual `<form>` in native apps. For more information refer the official docs from NativeScript & Angular.